# How can I quickly load data into datatable?

Tags: jquery, performance, datatables, sharepoint-online

I have a SharePoint list with quite a large number of entries (>100000)

I am trying to load them all into a jquery datatable to show to users.

Is it possible to do a deferred load in this scenario?
Or is it better to get the data in pages?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get the SharePoint list items in pages. SharePoint REST API supports paging while fetching SharePoint list items.

Check below resources for more information:

1. [Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-odata-query-operations-in-sharepoint-rest-requests)
2. [SharePoint REST API read large list items with pagination](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300510/sharepoint-rest-api-read-large-list-items-with-pagination)
3. [Paging list items returned from a SharePoint query](https://riptutorial.com/sharepoint/example/22037/paging-list-items-returned-from-a-query)

Comment: I am already getting the data in pages; I was wondering if it's possible to get only the first page and load into the datatable thereby speeding up the application.